# How should I initialize my list of tuples

Tags: list, initialization, tuples, ocaml

I have a function that takes a list of tuples and process it to obtain a tuple of 3 integers. 
I would now like to test it with a list of the tuples type I created but I'm unable to create this list.

Here is my tuple type :

```ml
    type t_votes = {valeur : string ; nombre : int };;
```

Here is my function :

```ml
let rec recap (l : t_votes list) : int * int * int =
    let (nb_oui,nb_non,nb_blanc) = recap(tl(l)) in
    if (l=[]) then
       (0,0,0)
    else if ((hd(l)).valeur = "oui") then
       (nb_oui+(hd(l)).nombre ,nb_non,nb_blanc)
    else if ((hd(l)).valeur = "non") then
       (nb_oui, nb_non + (hd(l)).nombre, nb_blanc)
    else if ((hd(l)).valeur = "blanc") then
       (nb_oui,nb_non,nb_blanc+(hd(l)).nombre)
    else
       failwith("liste invalide")
;;
```

And here is my vain attempt at declaring a list to test my function with :

```ml
let liste_votes : t_votes list = [("oui",120);("non",18);("blanc",20);("oui",20);("non",24);("blanc",25)];;
recap(liste_votes );;
```

Here is what tuareg gives me :

```ml
# let liste_votes : t_votes list = [("oui",120);("non",18);("blanc",20);("oui",20);("non",24);("blanc",25)];;
Characters 34-45:
  let liste_votes : t_votes list = [("oui",120);("non",18);("blanc",20);("oui",20);("non",24);("blanc",25)];;
                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^
Error: This expression has type 'a * 'b
       but an expression was expected of type t_votes
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create a value of a record type (because it is a record type and not a tuple, a tuple doesn't name its arguments), the syntax is the following:

```ml
{ valeur = "Some string" ; nombre = 13 }
```

If this syntax is too heavy for you, a common practice is to write a builder function:

```ml
let mk_vote valeur nombre = { valeur ; nombre }
```

Here I'm using another piece of syntax to instantiate a record value without using the `=` symbol. In that case, it's the same as writing `valeur = valeur` and `nombre = nombre`.

You can then write:

```ml
let votes = [ mk_vote "oui" 120 ; mk_vote "non" 18 ; mk_vote "blanc" 20 ; mk_vote "oui" 20 ; mk_vote "non" 24 ; mk_vote "blanc" 25 ]
```

```ml
let mk_vote (valeur, nombre) = { valeur ; nombre }
```

would work as well and let you write

```ml
let votes = List.map mk_vote [("oui",120);("non",18);("blanc",20);("oui",20);("non",24);("blanc",25)]
```

---

For some `vote` of the record type you can access the fields with `vote.valeur` and `vote.nombre`.
You can also use pattern-matching:

```ml
match vote with
| { valeur = v ; nombre = n } => (* ... *)
```

You can also make a record value from another one like so:

```ml
let vote = { valeur = "Some string" ; nombre = 13 } in
let vote' = { vote with valeur = "Some other string" } in
(* ... *)
```

Then `vote'.valeur` is `"Some other string"` while `vote'.nombre` is `vote.nombre`,
or `13` in that case.

---

Finally I couldn't help but notice you were using strings to represent different kind of votes, since there seem to be only three cases, a dedicated type would be more relevant (you are using ocaml after all which lets you handle data properly).

```ml
type vote_kind =
| Yes
| No
| Blank

type t_votes = {
  value : vote_kind ;
  amount : int ;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification about record types and tuples. Isn't there a way to create them faster inside of a list ?
Should I create a function generating random ones and adding them to a list to obtain the result I'm looking for ?